# Javascript: sum all found .data() for an array of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

We have an un-ordered list.

```
<ul>
 <li class="item" data-speed="500" data-delay="150"></li>
 <li class="item" data-speed="700"></li>
</ul>
```

I am working on a function to return the maximum sum speed+delay from the $('.item') array. In the current example it should return 700.

Something like

```
function sumArrayData(ar) { return maximum speed+delay for ar }
```

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Oh. What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript only.
You might not need to return the entire unsorted array. But this should do the trick so far.
I have to admit that actually don't know if its faster than the jquery solution, as you mentioned performance reasons.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
function maximum(e){
var arr = [];
var delay = 0;
var speed = 0;
var res = 0;
for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++)
{
    speed = parseInt(e.item(i).getAttribute('data-speed'), 10);
    delay = parseInt(e.item(i).getAttribute('data-delay') || 0, 10);
    res = speed + delay;
    arr.push(res);
}

return arr.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
}
var myMax = maximum(elements);
alert(myMax[0]);
```

Comment: This also good, and I think it's even better than the plain JS provided by previous developer. I might do some corrections to your answer to make it exactly how I use it.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.item').map(function() {
    var data = $(this).data();
    return data.speed + (data.delay || 0);
}).get());
```

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5p0rthzb/)

---

Because you asked for a plain javascript solution in the comment below, I converted the script.
Here you go:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('item')).map(function(elm) {
    var data = {
        speed: parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-speed'), 10),
        delay: parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-delay'), 10)
    };
    return data.speed + (data.delay || 0);
}));
```

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5p0rthzb/1/) for this one.

Here is the [performance comparison](http://jsperf.com/get-max-value-from-data-values) of the two code snippets.

Comment: Thanks @friedi. I am grateful for your input. I am gonna test your solution right now and provide feedback or confirm your answer. I was also wondering of there is also a very minimal plain javascript only solution for this, because I need best performance. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, both work excellent, your comparison example is stunningly wonderful.

Comment: IE8 crashes on .map(), is there an alternative for it?

Comment: Use the **Polyfill**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill